# Не работает проект в IDEA под WIN 10, а под Ubuntu работает

Tags: intellij-idea

Есть проект, который упорно отказывается работать на одной машине. Отдавал проект другому человеку, у него работает. Поднял виртуальную машину, тоже заработал.

Есть впечатление, что что то не так с самой IDEA. Поделитесь опытом решения подобных ситуаций. Нужные логи предоставлю, только скажите какие.

Comment: Опыт подсказывает мне, что возможно дело в версии JDK - или конфликт версий 32/64 или что-то типа такого. Это не рецепт, а так наблюдения.

Comment: Удали IDEA и JDK, для удаления воспользуйся Revo Unistall или любой другой подобной программой, которая может почистить и реестр от мусора. потом поставь всё заново.

Comment: Соберите проект без использования IDEA. Таким образом сможете понять - виновата ли она.

Answer (score 0):

В общем то логика понятна и с читкой реестра и переустановкой ПО, и битность и меет право на жизнь, но нет. Не прокатило. Переустановил windows.